# Change by value reference in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have RangeClass and a MyClass and it has RangeClass property.

```
 public class RangeClass{
    public int min;
    public int max;
 }
```

and

```
 public class MyClass{
     RangeClass range;
     public void setRange(Range r){

     }
 }
```

I want to create several instances of MyClass and the myClass.range is a reference of a RangeClass(say, defaultRange). So whenever I change the defaultRange, it will reflect to all the range property of myclass. I want to find out how can I do this without going through each of the instances. I found this [post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/225286/how-do-i-know-whether-variable-is-pass-by-value-or.html), but I'm not sure how to modify the accepted answer to achieve my goal.

**UPDATE:** Code below shows two range classes that are used as property of MyClass classes and shows how to access the range method.
    public class Range{
        public float min;
        public float max;
        public Range(float a, float b){
            min = a;
            max = b;
        }

```
    public bool Contains(float a){
        if (a >= min && a<=max){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyClass{
    public static Range range;
    public void SetRange(Range r){
        range = r;
    }
    public bool Cointains(float num){
        return range.Contains(num);
    }
}

public class OtherClass{
    MyClass instance1;
    MyClass instance2;

    public OtherClass(){
        Range range1 = new Range(1,5); //creates instance of Range
        Range range2 = new Range(6,10); //creates another instance of Range

        instance1 = new MyClass();
        instance1.SetRange(range1);

        instance2 = new MyClass();
        instance2.SetRange(range2);

        bool isInSetA = instance1.Contains(4);
        bool isInSetB = instance2.Contains(4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior for reference types, since you're sharing single `RangeClass` instance between several instances of `MyClass`. If you don't want to reflect changes, then:

1 - you can do your `RangeClass` immutable, so, you couldn't change its instances at all:

```
public class RangeClass
{    
    public int Min { get; private set; }
    public int Max { get; private set; }

    public RangeClass(int min, int max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }
}
```

2 - You can add a creation of default `RangeClass` instances at `MyClass` constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public MyClass()
     {
         range = new RangeClass { min = 0, max = 100 };
     }

     RangeClass range;

     public void setRange(Range r)
     {
     }
 }
```

If you **do** want to reflect the changes, just made a `public static` property or `public static readonly` field in `RangeClass`, which will correspond to default range:

```
public class RangeClass{
    public int min;
    public int max;

    public static readonly RangeClass DefaultRange = new RangeClass { min = 0, max = 100 };
 }
```

Comment: I got another issue. How do I access the method of RangeClass. I updated my post to reflect my current code.

Comment: Your code contradicts your text. You've set different ranges for each `MyClass` instance, and you want to check some value within default range?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. So basically, what Im trying to do here is a have a set of MyClass instances with range1 as property and another set of MyClass with range2. If i change the range1, all the MyClass instances that has reference to it will reflect the value.

Comment: I managed to access the RangeMethod by exposing a method on MyClass to access it. :)

Comment: You have this behavior out of the box. This is how the reference types in .NET behave. I can't see any necessity for `static` here. All you need is to cache `range1` and `range2` references.

Answer (score 1):

Make range a static property of MyClass so that all MyClass objects share the same range.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the static modifier what you want?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

E.g: Pseudo code

```
Class ClassA
{
    public int IntA = 0;
    public int IntB = 5;
}

class ClassB
{
    public static ClassA;
}

main
{
    ClassB MyClassB;
    ClassB MySecondClassB;

    MySecndClassB.ClassA.IntA = 1; //The vale of 1 will be overwritten by
    MyClassB.ClassA.IntA = 5; //the value of 5 here, for all instances of ClassB.
    System.Diagnostics.Print(MySecndClassB.ClassA.IntA.ToString() + " - " + MyClassB.ClassA.IntA.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I cannot access the member of ClassA in the main method using your approach. Its giving me an error in ClassB, I think you're  missing a variable name in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your range property from instance to Static. This will allow RangeClass to be viewed from any of the MyClass instance with default value or modified state.

```
public class MyClass{
     public static RangeClass range;
     public void setRange(Range r){

     }
 }
```